# Jquery :contains for 2 different string

Tags: jquery

Hi so I have 2 different product title on different page

```
<h1 class="productTitle">Arizona Sand</h1>
<h1 class="productTitle">Arizona Sand 3 Squares</h1>
```

I use the `:contains()` if it contain that word when I visit the product page

```
if($(".productTitle:contains('Arizona Sand')").length > 0){
    //Do Stuff;
}

if($(".productTitle:contains('Arizona Sand 3 Squares')").length > 0){
    //Do Stuff;
}
```

But the problem when I visit the 'Arizona Sand 3 Squares' page it's running both of the if statements.  So is there another method of doing this?

Comment: Why not do `$(".productTitle").text() == 'Arizona Sand')`?

Comment: This would also work, but it was my logic that was a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would solve it:

```
if($(".productTitle:contains('Arizona Sand 3 Squares')").length > 0){
    //Do Stuff;
}
else if($(".productTitle:contains('Arizona Sand')").length > 0){
    //Do Stuff;
}
```

the logics behind it: you first check for the most rare situation, and ONLY IF that isn't the case, you check for the more common situation.

This way, it will never take both.

Comment: @OpuLance Glad I could help. If my answer was a good answer that solved your problem, please accept it as "answer", so others can see it. Good luck with your future code.